# Related rows based on text columns

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, search

Given that I have a table with a column of TEXT in it (MySQL or SQlite) is it possible to use the value of that column in a way that I could find similar rows with somewhat related text values?

For example, I if I wanted to find *related rows* to row_3 - both 1 & 2 would match:

```
row_1 = this is about sports
row_2 = this is about study
row_3 = this is about study and sports
```

I know that I could use FULLTEXT or FTS3 if I had a key word I wanted to `MATCH` against the column values - but I'm just trying to find text that is somewhat related among the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong hammer to pound that screw in.  A single string in a database column isn't the way to store that data.  You can't easily get at the part you care about, which is the individual words.

There is a lot of research into the problem of comparison of text.  If you're serious about this need, you'll want to start reading about the variety of techniques in that problem domain.

The first clue is that you want to access / index the data not by complete text string, but by word or sentence fragment (unless you're interested in words that are spelled similarly being matched together, which is harder).

As an example of one technique, generate a chain out of your sentences by grabbing overlapping sets of three words, and store the chain.  Then you can search for entries that have a large number of chain segments in common.  A set of chain segments for your statements above would be:

> row_1 = this is about sports
>
> row_2 =
> this is about study
>
> row_3 = this is
> about study and sports

- this is about (3 matches)
- is about sports
- is about study (2 matches)
- about study and
- study and sports

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports a fulltext search option called `QUERY EXPANSION`.  The idea is that you search for a keyword, it finds a row, and then it uses the words in that row as keywords, to search for more matching rows.

```
SELECT ... FROM StudiesTable WHERE MATCH(description_text) 
  AGAINST ('sports' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

Read about it here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Comment: Nice, but again I don't have a keyword to search for - I'm just going off the data already in the row trying to find related rows. However, bookmarked this as helpful should I ever need it.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that with MySQL fulltext search.  The pattern must be a string literal, not a column name, parameter, or user variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be enough to take each relevant word (more than 4 letters? or comparing against a list of commom words?) in the base row using them as keywords for the fulltext search and building a tmp table (`id, row_matched_id, count`) to record the matches for each row adding 1 to count when it matches. At the end you'll get in the tmp table all the lines that matched and how many times they matched (how many relevant words were the same).
If you want to run it once against the whole database and keep the results, use a persisted table, add a column for the id of the base row and do the search for each new row inserted (or updated) to update the results table.
Using this results table you can find quickly the rows matching more words of the base row without doing the search again.

Edit: with this you can "score" the results, for example, if you count x relevant words in the base row, you can calculate a score in % as (matches/x * 100) and filter all results with for example less than 50% matches. In your example, each row_1 and row_2 would give 50% if considering relevants only words with more than 4 letters or 67% if you consider all the words.